# How to publish website to github and have preview of the website show?

Tags: html, css, github, web-testing, vs-web-site-project

I recently finished designing my personal website on HTML. I designed the website from scratch and did not use any templates. I was wondering how to upload my HTML code to Github and have it actually display the website. I was able to upload the code to Github but could not figure out how to preview the webpage.

Comment: Have you checked out the quickstart guide on the Github pages website? https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are two routes to accomplish this:

1. [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)
   This allows you to host the static content of your GitHub Repository as a custom `<username>.github.io` webpage.
2. [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/)
   This will serve files from your Git repository as a web server would.  It would let you preview your website (without changing the repository name), but does not have a cool URL like GitHub pages.

Comment: Thanks, the issue I was having was with Github Pages. The main file (homepage) needs to be called "index.html" or the page will not correctly load.